# MacOS: Get Notification System Update

Tags: macos, software-update, notifications, preferences

How do I get notification that there is an update for the MacOS system? I can find some questions on how to turn it off, but my problem is that it doesn’t appear to notify me at all.

The last update is one I read about. After that, I went to

```
System Preferences | Software Update
```

After that I checked manually. On then did I see any notification.

My selected Advanced settings are:

- Check for updates
- Download new updates …
- Install macOS updates
- Install system data files …

MacOS 10.14.3

Answer (score 1):

On my iMac I have AppStore app in the dock. Whenever I have a software update, a number appears on the AppStore icon indicating how many updates I have. This applies to System Updates as well. I think that is the only way I'm notified.

Comment: Thanks, but it’s not the apps I’m worried about. It’s the actual System updates. They used to appear with the App Store, but now they’re in System Preferences.

Comment: since when? are you running Mojave?